C# Dev Kit And .NET Core Test Explorer can not see XUnit tests under 3.1 but can under 8.0
I'm using VSCode 1.92.2, C# Dev Kit v1.9.55 and .NET Core Test Explorer extension v0.7.8, however none of them can list my XUnit tests under .NET 3.1, but if I switch to project with .NET 8.0 all tests are enlisted just fine. Is .NET 3.1 no longer supported by these extensions?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Best regards,
SetNug

"Is .NET [Core] 3.1 no longer supported by these extensions?" That's a real possibility as .NET Core 3.1 itself was no longer supported by Microsoft after 22nd December 2022.
